# (CLOSED) "ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence", even though the sequence is not empty

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a Python challenge, and the challenge says:

```
The goal of this challenge is to analyze a binary string consisting of only zeros and ones.
Your code should find the biggest number of consecutive zeros in the string.
For example, given the string:

"1001101000110"
The biggest number of consecutive zeros is 3.

Define a function named consecutive_zeros that takes a single parameter,
which is the string of zeros and ones. Your function should return the number described above.
```

I used this code:

```
def consecutive_zeros(s):
    e = [len(i) for i in s.split('1') if not i == ""]
    '''
    Split at every 1, remove empty residue, 
    and get the length of every consecutive string of zeros.
    '''
    return max(e) # Error happens here
    

print(consecutive_zeros("1001101000110"))
```

and I get the error mentioned in the title.
The weird thing is, I can add `print(max(e))` above the `return` line, and it actually prints the largest value in the list, or `print(len(e))` and it shows the length (which is greater than 0, so it's not empty).

Why does it say the sequence is empty when it clearly isn't?

**EDIT** For some reason, using it in another IDE fixes the problem...? Both are online IDEs.

Comment: This code cannot produce that error.  However it does have an indentation error, so it can't possibly run as shown.  Your real code must be different.

Comment: If you're talking about the "comment" (single quotes), I just did that for readability. Otherwise, where is the indentation error?

Comment: Run it myself. The comment should be indented backwards, but when I did move it back, I got printed "3" as expected.

Comment: Yes, the error is the comment.  The triple quotes are indented too far.

Comment: I fixed the indentation in the question, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I ran that exact code and it works.  I say again, your actual code must be different.

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of passing in an empty string to the function.

```
In [73]: def consecutive_zeros(s):
    ...:     e = [len(i) for i in s.split('1') if not i == ""]
    ...:     return max(e)
    ...: 
In [76]: consecutive_zeros("")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-db8f321b1ffd> in <module>
----> 1 consecutive_zeros("")

<ipython-input-73-37af30e2aebb> in consecutive_zeros(s)
      1 def consecutive_zeros(s):
      2     e = [len(i) for i in s.split('1') if not i == ""]
----> 3     return max(e)
      4 

ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

So just check that the input is not empty before running the list comprehension. Moreover, when the input is a string of "1111111" `max(e)` will throw the same error so only return the max of `e` if the value is truthy.

```
def consecutive_zeros(s):
    if not s: return 0
    e = [len(i) for i in s.split('1') if not i == ""]
    return max(e) if e else 0

In [79]: consecutive_zeros("")
Out[79]: 0

In [80]: consecutive_zeros("1001101000110")
Out[80]: 3

In [99]: consecutive_zeros("1111111")
Out[99]: 0
```

Comment: I used your code and the error remained (I removed the `In[]` and `Out[]` things, and called the function). Also, the string is NOT empty; I put `print(len(s))` at the beginning of the function body, and it printed 13.

Comment: @ohhellothere ah so the error still remains when I pass in a string with all `1` in them. What is the expected output for this case?

Comment: The expected output should be 3, because the maximum amount of consecutive zeros is 3.

Comment: No I mean for a string like `11111111111111` that is where the error is coming from.

Comment: It should be 0, because there aren't any consecutive zeros in that string.

Comment: @ohhellothere check the updated answer.